# Does any one have Idea to get these functionalities with the plugin wp-multi-network

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization

I am using the plugin wp-multi-network(http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multi-network/) to maintain child networks under multi site.Using this I can create child networks.But I can’t set sign up functionality to child networks .And If the main network is **mainnetwork.com** and **childnetwork** has the domain like **childnetwork**. mainnetwork.com .The sites set under this child network would not get the domain as site. childnetwork. mainnetwork.com  .

Does any body have Ideas to get these functionalities? And does any one w’d like to share your experience and the knowledge you have with this plugin?

(I got got answers by my self and updating the topic .So it may be useful to others)
The child networks **childnetwork1. mainnetwork.com** and **childnetwork2. mainnetwork.com** also should have the sign up functionality .If I want to give a complete access on **childnetwork1. mainnetwork.com** to a person 'X' or group "X group" .X can able to use it as his own blog network and he can let others to create blogs same as me.So I still  have control on that child network and at the same time X acts as super admin for the blog network.

The basic purpose of the wp-multi-network plugin is the same.Presently one cannot able to set signup functionality to child networks .But Admin of child netoworks as well as the super admin can create sub-sites under child networks from their **dashboards** .
       So this a multisite can be used as network of networks .

Comment: Could you please provider a clearer example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to set sign up functionality for child networks too.So any one can create the blogs under this child network .
Currently an admin of child network only create new blogs from his end(from admin panel) and assign user permissions or new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start over with that in the Wordpress [Support Forums of the WP Multi Network Plugin](http://wordpress.org/tags/wp-multi-network?forum_id=10). I can only suggest this because I do not have any special experience with that plugin and I assume that it has DNS implications for the hosts you'd like to use it on.

Additionally you might want to make your question more clear and tell more about the setup you're running (Server, Services, DNS and so on). Which steps did you have already done and the like.

But probably you find your answer already in that forum.

Comment: Thanks I will try asking there .By the way My site is hosted on shared hosting .

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your shared hosting, but normally DNS is not offered with it. If the plugin needs DNS configuration this might not be compatible with your hosting.